# 0-5v to 5 to 0 v analog level conveter

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative

I have a HBLED driver that for some reason, uses a 5V-0V linear control voltage. The driver has the LED OFF at 5V and full on a 0V.  Id like to be able to use the drivers with a 0v-5v signal. Im pretty sure this can be done with a microprocessor, but the LED driver uses an Analog voltage, not PWM and a linear analog voltage is required.  I did look through the similar answers, but could not extrapolate to what I needed. Im disabled now and I wish my brain worked as it did earlier in life.   SUMMING it up, I need what I think should be a an OP Amp with negative gain value, taking 0-5VDC and returning linear 5V to 0V signal.

Comment: Is crossing plus and minus wires an option?

Comment: only if multiple power supplies are used, they share a common ground.  In keeping the solution inexpensive, adding an isolated dc-dc converter will add a large expense.

Answer (score 3):

Or what you really want to do is subtract your 0-5V control signal from a 5V reference....

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fa6cf7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

**NOTE** Your op-amp either needs to be powered by >> +- 5V preferred, or a single supply rail-to rail model >5V. if you don't mind a little roll off at the ends.

Comment: So would an inverting opamp with negative gain work?  I didnt see the answer like that, but a Vref of 5V acting against the 0-5V signal into opAmp?

Comment: @RDTECH See update

Comment: WOW, you are amazing.. I tried it on the simulator, couldnt get it working and when I got back to pag you had already posted print.... Let me Breadboard this up and see.  Thanks so much for now..  DO you think any wide supply R to R OpAMp will work good..

Comment: @RDTECH It depends on the frequencies you plan on using, though for the application you describe, I do not see that being an issue.